# Is there a way to pull more than one row from google sheets using appsript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Hello guys below is a link to my google sheet database please i want to implement a feature that will allow me pull data from google sheets to html table  when they select a date range e.g( from 12/1/2019 to 12/7/2019) and a specific state(e.g California) will display only  the records for california that fall into the date range  please i will be grateful if i have the solution to this as it is a bottle neck for me to deliver on this project. Thanks[

```js
code.gs
function getTableData(fac, dataaaa) {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("data2");
 
  var allSheetRowData=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 
  var sheetHeaderData=allSheetRowData[0];
 
 
  var dateColIndex =   sheetHeaderData.indexOf("Date");
  var stateColIndex = sheetHeaderData.indexOf("state");
var array=[];

var  hey = fac.toString();
array.push(sheetHeaderData);

var  dat = dataaaa.toString();

  var rowData;
      

  for(var i=1; i<allSheetRowData.length-1 ;i++){
    
   if((allSheetRowData[i][dateColIndex]) == dat && allSheetRowData[i][stateColIndex]== hey){

      rowData=allSheetRowData[i];
     array.push(rowData);

Logger.log(rowData);
      break;  
   
  }
 
  }
     return array;   
  }

function include (filename){
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();

}
```

```js
function extractAction () {
  var stateVal = document.getElementById ('extractstate');
  var datepic = document.getElementById ('extractdate').value;

  if (stateVal[stateVal.selectedIndex].value == '') {
    alerterror ('Please choose the state');
  } else if (datepic == '') {
    alerterror ('Please choose the  Date');
  } else {
    var dataaaa = datepic.toString ();
    var fac = stateVal.options[stateVal.selectedIndex].text;

    alertsuccess ('You successfully pulled the data');
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler (generateTable)
      .getTableData (fac, dataaaa);
    //generateTable();
  }
}

function generateTable (dataArray) {
  var newarray = TwoDimensional (dataArray, 2);

  var newarray_2 = newarray.slice (1);

  newarray_2.forEach (function (r) {
    r.forEach (function (val, key) {
      var arrayhead = newarray[0];

      var count = 0;
      console.log (r);
      var tbody = document.getElementById ('tableID');
      var row = tbody.insertRow (count++);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell (0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell (1);
      cell1.innerHTML = arrayhead[key];
      cell2.innerHTML = val;
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody id="tableID">
</tbody>
</table>
```

[html table like this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jksf59Yep9N3kMX6KzuokZ5bix8OHaqtoOlgSj3dZp0/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Your code seems in general all right (apart from some minor error which are probably typing mistakes). Can you explained more in detail what your problem with the code code is / what you want to change? Right now it pulls rows where the date exactly matches. Is your question about to retrieve instead all dates within a certain range?

Comment: I assume you have a `doGet()` function somewhere in your code?

Comment: PLEASE HERE IS THE SHAREABLE  LINK TO THE  SHEETS thanks...https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jksf59Yep9N3kMX6KzuokZ5bix8OHaqtoOlgSj3dZp0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: ok let me make it clearer

Comment: Are you familiar with what the `break` statement does?

Comment: now i want it to be able to loop through the sheets and display appropriate data base on user input date range....take for instance i enter start date 12/1/2019 to 12/10/2019 and california as the state....it will loop through and display all the data related to california and  that falls between the date range the user inputed and display it dynamically on an html table ...please u have the picture file i sent as a guide i want it displayed that way on html table...i hope this makes it clearer

Comment: yes it breaks out of the loop; please could you help me modify my code to display the data as it is in the picture i posted thanks

Comment: please i guess the method should carry 3 arguments, startdate, enddate, state.... this should form the arguments please give me a code that will print a table base on this arguments...thanks and sorry for the unclear question

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTableData(fac, data) {
  if(fac && data) {
    var sh=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("data2");
    var vA=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    var hA=vA[0];
    var hObj={};
    hA.forEach(function(e,i){hObj[e]=i;})
    var array=[];
    array.push(hA);
    for(var i=1; i<vA.length-1 ;i++){
      if((vA[i][hObj['date']])==data && vA[i][hObj['state']]==fac){
        array.push(vA[i]);  
      }
    }
    return array;   
  }
}
```

You were using 'Date' for getting date header index but that doesn't agree with you image.

[image]

I would do it like this:

On the server side:

```
function getTableData(fac, data) {
  if(fac && data) {
    var sh=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("data2");
    var vA=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    var hA=vA[0];
    var hObj={};
    var html='<style>td,th{border:1px solid black}</style><table><tr>';
    hA.forEach(function(e,i){hObj[e]=i;html+='<th>' + e + '</th>';});
    html+='</tr>';
    var array=[];
    array.push(hA);
    for(var i=1; i<vA.length-1 ;i++){
      if((vA[i][hObj['date']])==data && vA[i][hObj['state']]==fac){
        html+='<tr>';
        vA[i].forEach(function(e,i){
          html+='<td>' + e + '</td>';
        })
        html+='</tr>';
        array.push(vA[i]);  
      }
    }
    html+='</table>';
    return {array:array,html:html};   
  }
}
```

on the client side:

```
 google.script.run
 .withSuccessHandler (function(obj){
    document.getElementById ('tableID').innerHTML=obj.html;
 })
 .getTableData (fac,dataaaa);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code...now how do I display it on HTML table...I need a code that will create a table column dynamically to fit the number of rows which fall into the given condition so see the picture and the google sheet as a guide...in essence if 1 row in the Goole sheet  fall in between the date range only one column plus the header column are generated same if two  or four or 10 rows falls into the condition a column is automatically generated for them.in Goolge sheet...thanks